# Mysql, multiple queries in combination with JOIN and SORT BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a beginner of MySQL and have gotten stuck.
I think I have to make some kind of a "advanced" subquery to solve my problem but I can't find out how.  Is someone able to help me?

***The first query*** joins three tables, "annons", "kontering_annons" and "member".
The result are the unique "annons.id" entries. (In my case 3 results).
The problem is that I need to find the ***last*** entry in the table "kontering_annons" for each unique "annons.id". Which this query does not.

```
SELECT  annons.id, annons.id_user, member.saldo, member.id,
kontering_annons.id_annons, kontering_annons.dat_bet_till, 
kontering_annons.id_kontering_a, kontering_annons.dat_ut_member
FROM annons
LEFT JOIN kontering_annons 
ON kontering_annons.id_annons = annons.id
LEFT JOIN member
ON member.id = annons.id_user
WHERE (annons.status='3' OR annons.status='4')
AND annons.typ='d'
AND annons.startar < NOW() - 48*60*60
AND kontering_annons.dat_bet_till < CURRENT_DATE()
AND member.saldo >= $day_price
GROUP BY annons.id
```

***The second*** query presents the ***last*** entry in the table "kontering_annons for each "id_annons". (In my case 18 results).
I think I need to combine this query with the one above to be able to find only the three unique entries whith the ***latest*** entry-id. But how?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM kontering_annons a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_annons, dat_bet_till, max(id_kontering_a) 
AS maxid 
FROM kontering_annons 
GROUP BY id_annons) 
AS b 
ON a.id_kontering_a = b.maxid
```

Comment: If you do not mind, could you please update the question with your table schema and small sample data set for each? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
  a.id, 
  a.id_user, 
  m.saldo, 
  m.id,
  k.id_annons, 
  k.dat_bet_till, 
  k.id_kontering_a, 
  k.dat_ut_member
FROM annons a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
      id_annons, 
      dat_bet_till, 
      max(id_kontering_a) AS maxid 
    FROM kontering_annons 
    GROUP BY id_annons
) km ON a.id = km.id_annons
LEFT JOIN kontering_annons k  ON k.id_annons     = km.id_annons 
                             AND k.id_kontering_a = km.maxid 
LEFT JOIN member           m  ON m.id            = a.id_user
WHERE (a.status='3' OR a.status='4')
AND a.typ='d'
AND a.startar < NOW() - 48*60*60
AND k.dat_bet_till < CURRENT_DATE()
AND m.saldo >= $day_price
```

What I have done here, is `INNER JOIN` the table `annons` with:

```
    SELECT 
      id_annons, 
      dat_bet_till, 
      max(id_kontering_a) AS maxid 
    FROM kontering_annons 
    GROUP BY id_annons
```

`ON a.id = km.id_annons` then `JOIN` it with `kontering_annons`, selecting only all the data of that table that had the last `id_kontering_a` by  joining it on `kid_kontering_a = km.maxid`.

**Note that**: I used `INNER JOIN` then two `LEFT JOIN` to keep it `LEFT JOIN` otherwise if you did `LEFT JOIN` then `INNER JOIN` to get the max ids it will be an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Hi, Mahmoud. Great!!! I think this solved my problem. Except for one missing dot in (AND kid_kontering_a) should be (AND k.id_kontering_a) it seems to work. Thank´s a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may save the following query to a temp table.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM kontering_annons a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_annons, dat_bet_till, dat_ut_member, 
max(id_kontering_a) AS maxid 
FROM kontering_annons 
GROUP BY id_annons) AS b 
ON a.id_kontering_a = b.maxid
AND a.dat_bet_till < CURRENT_DATE()
```

Then join the temp table with your main query replacing the kontering_annons table.

```
SELECT  annons.id, annons.id_user, member.saldo, member.id,
tempT.id_annons, tempT.dat_bet_till, 
tempT.id_kontering_a, tempT.dat_ut_member
FROM annons
LEFT JOIN tempT 
ON tempT.id_annons = annons.id
LEFT JOIN member
ON member.id = annons.id_user
WHERE (annons.status='3' OR annons.status='4')
AND annons.typ='d'
AND annons.startar < NOW() - 48*60*60
AND member.saldo >= $day_price
GROUP BY annons.id
```